# Run shell script file once after reboot

Tags: bash, systemd, terminal, cron, reboot

I am stucked on how to execute a shell script only once after the machine reboots, the file that I have has the following content where I am writing a test to get only the first element from the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A" >> /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt
echo "B" >> /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt 
echo "C" >> /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt

sleep 10  #this sleep I put only to the lines below be executed when the machine came back to the desktop
test=$(sort /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt | uniq | head -n 1)
echo $test >> /home/vtr/Documents/finaltest.txt
```

I already went through cron and by systemd but on both of them instead have only `A` as output I am getting a file which was ran several times:

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

And this is my `/etc/systemd/system/testing.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=One test script
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/vtr/Documents/testing.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also tried to perform a test only writing "A","B" and "C" without the sleep, test and echo lines above `echo "C" >> /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt` but I am having the same thing where the output file should be:

```
A
B
C
```

But in fact it's printing and running several times also:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Is there anyway to run a script after reboot once?

Comment: Do you ever truncate `/home/vtr/Documents/test.txt`? These "several times" may be from all the previous runs (previous reboots). Side note: this is why you test such things with `date` instead of `echo some fixed string`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can simplify your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "A\nB\nC\n" >> /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt

sleep 10
sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt |tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt | head -1 >> /home/vtr/Documents/finaltest.txt
```

And if you add in `cron` records like:

```
@reboot /home/vtr/Documents/testing.sh
```

you will have script execured on boot

For testing you ca make the script like this:

```
printf "A\nB\nC\n" >> /home/vtr/Documents/1.txt
    
    sleep 10
    sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt >/home/vtr/Documents/2.txt
sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt|tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt >/home/vtr/Documents/3.txt
sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt |tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt | head -1 >> /home/vtr/Documents/4.txt
```

and check the content of these files.
also you can add after first line and make it

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -x
```

Comment: I did it now but I am still getting test.txt and finaltest.txt files with lots of A,B,C and A appends on each respective file, the aim is being append only A at the finaltest.txt file and A,B,C at test.txt. What I am thinking weird is why after reboot the script is run several times instead once.

Comment: @xts, remove the service and keep only cron. And check in cron log what happen. Will try to align the things

Comment: @xts, check my edited answer

Comment: I think that it didn't work here, when I after did this command: ```sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt |tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt | head -1 >> /home/vtr/Documents/finaltest.txt``` at the gnome terminal outside the script it returned me the first three letters, but when I did it again it returned me nothing and when I executed the whole script the text file returned me the same (all void) I don't know why, it is due because the several times that the file is executed after the reboot.

Comment: I let only cron active, the systemd I have deleted it.

Comment: @zeus, split the line and check where it does not work. In my environment I have no problem. Also you can make `cron` to send you mail with the result (to see some STDERR outputs)

Comment: Do you say about split the line of the file or at the printf line? I am gonna give a test on other machines here to check if is the same is happening, thank you!

Comment: @zeus, I added some instructions to debug the script

Comment: I ran this script which you suggested:

```
printf "A\nB\nC\n" >> /home/vtr/Documents/1.txt
    
    sleep 10
    sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt >/home/vtr/Documents/2.txt
sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt|tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt >/home/vtr/Documents/3.txt
sort -u /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt |tee /home/vtr/Documents/test.txt | head -1 >> /home/vtr/Documents/4.txt
```

It generated me 4 files (1,2,3,4) but each one of them is in blank, and that ```#!/bin/bash set -x``` at the beginning of the file the error non-existent file or directory. I am gonna give new try

Comment: @zeus, see my updated answer about `-x`

Comment: Hi @Romeo, I am gonna give another test and another check... thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the crontab with **`@reboot`** parameter? Perhaps you should add `@reboot /path/to/bashscript.sh` to the end of your crontab file with `crontab -e` command. Also change the `>>` operators in your bash script to `>` operator and try again.

Comment: The `>>` has a purpose though. I think the comment shows the culprit of the outcome.